# str_replace syntax in perl script

Tags: sql, perl, syntax, replace

In my below script, the `str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),'''','_')` doesn't seem to work.
I want to replace single quotes with underscores for my arguments. For example:

```
Input: `S'achin`  
Result: `S_achin`

 $sql = 'select rtrim(f_admin_disabled),'."\n".
       '       convert(varchar,t_password,101),'."\n".
       '       rtrim(c_email),'."\n".
       '       str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),'''','_'),'."\n".
       '       rtrim(c_mgr_email)'."\n".
       '  from tuserprofile'."\n".
       ' where ic_user1 = '."'$user_id'"."\n";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have single quotes in a single quoted string to produce `str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),'''','_'),` you need to either escape them:

```
'       str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),\'\'\'\',\'_\'),'
```

or use a different delimiter:

```
q!       str_replace(rtrim(c_manager),'''','_'),!
```

Answer (score 2):

to replace a character in string

```
$string=~s/'/_/g;
```

Syntax

```
$string=~s/<string>/<replace_string>/g;
```

Comment: There're no needs to escape the quote and to have the `i` modifier.

Comment: how will use on the above select statement

Answer (score 0):

Use this subroutine.

```
sub str_replace {
  my ($s) = @_;

  $s =~ s/'/_/g;

  return $s;
}
```